# How to grep the line number of result of that particular file, from multiple files

Tags: linux, unix, grep, gunzip

I'm trying to use grep to output the line number of the result  from multiple files.

Example:

Name of file 1 is `test1.zip`; inside `test1.zip`, the content is

```
123
234
```

Name of file 2 is `test2.zip`; inside `test2.zip`, the content is

```
456
789
```

Now, this is only a simplified scenario. In the actual scenario, I have multiple files like that.

Right now, I'm doing this:

```
gunzip -c test* | grep -n 789
```

The result is

```
4;789
```

But what I want to see is

```
2;789
```

Because 789 is the second line in its own file, `test2.zip`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grep only sees a stream of lines and has no way of knowing when a file ends and a new one starts, so it doesn't know about line numbering per file.

Instead of piping the output of `gunzip` to grep, you can use `zgrep` directly:

```
$ zgrep -n 789 test*
test2.gz:2:789
```

If you don't have `zgrep`, you can use `find` with `-exec` as follows:

```
$ find -name 'test*' -exec bash -c 'gunzip -c "$1" | grep -n 789 ' _ {} \;
2:789
```

This finds all files matching `test*` and runs your pipeline on them. The way to bring a pipeline into `find -exec` is spawning a subshell with `bash -c 'command' _ {}` and then refer to the filename in `command` as `$1`.

This does give you the result you asked for, but if you also want the filename, you could have it printed if the `-exec` exits successfully:

```
$ find -name 'test*' -exec bash -c 'gunzip -c "$1" | grep -n 789 ' _ {} \; -print
2:789
./test2.gz
```